# How to @Autowire objects in Validator classes?

Tags: spring, autowired

Is it possible to Autowire an object in a Validation class? I keep getting null for the object that is supposed to be Autowired...

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: That is identical to how my project is laid out.  what is even more confusing is that the @Autowire is working on the @Controller classes. the problem is that i am instantiating the AccessRequestValidator class inside of a Controller (vs setting it up in the a context xml file).  I have annotated the Validator with @Component, but none of the @Autowire are working...

Answer (score 23):

Are your Validation class **an enabled Spring bean** ??? If not, you always will get null for your object autowired. Make sure you have enabled your Validation class.

And do not forget enable The Annotation config bean post-processor (see <context:annotation-config /> element)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

How to enable your Validation class as a managed Spring bean. Either

**1°** By using xml (As shown above)

```
<beans ...>
    <bean class="AccessRequestValidator"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

**2°** By using annotation instead (Notice @Component just above class)

```
@Component
public class AccessRequestValidator implements Validator {

}
```

**But** to enable Spring annotated component scanning, you **must** enable a bean-post processor (notice <context:component-scan element)

```
<beans ...>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="<PUT_RIGHT_HERE_WHICH_ROOT_PACKAGE_SHOULD_SPRING_LOOK_FOR_ANY_ANNOTATED_BEAN>"/>
</beans>
```

Inside your Controller, just do it (**Do not use** new operator)

**Choose one of the following strategies**

```
public class MyController implements Controller {

    /**
      * You can use FIELD @Autowired
      */
    @Autowired
    private AccessRequestValidator accessRequestValidator;

    /**
      * You can use PROPERTY @Autowired
      */
    private AccessRequestValidator accessRequestValidator;
    private @Autowired void setAccessRequestValidator(AccessRequestValidator accessRequestValidator) {
        this.accessRequestValidator = accessRequestValidator;
    }

    /**
      * You can use CONSTRUCTOR @Autowired
      */
    private AccessRequestValidator accessRequestValidator;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(AccessRequestValidator accessRequestValidator) {
        this.accessRequestValidator = accessRequestValidator;
    }   

}
```

**UPDATE**

Your web app structure should looks like

```
<CONTEXT-NAME>/
       WEB-INF/
           web.xml
           <SPRING-SERVLET-NAME>-servlet.xml
           business-context.xml
           classes/
               /com
                   /wuntee
                       /taac
                           /validator
                               AccessRequestValidator.class
           lib/
               /**
                 * libraries needed by your project goes here
                 */
```

Your **web.xml** should looks like (NOTICE contextConfigLocation context-param and ContextLoaderListener)

```
<web-app version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
                       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <!--If your business-context.xml lives in the root of classpath-->
        <!--replace by classpath:business-context.xml-->
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/business-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name><SPRING-SERVLET-NAME></servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name><SPRING-SERVLET-NAME></servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Your <SPRING-SERVLET-NAME>-servlet.xml should looks like (Notice i am using Spring 2.5 - replace if you are using 3.0)

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <!--ANY HANDLER MAPPING-->
    <!--ANY VIEW RESOLVER-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wuntee.taac"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

Comment: I think he's referring to validator classes that are *not* managed by Spring, in which case `annotation-config` won't make a difference.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by 'managed/not-managed by spring'... i have a class that implements Validator and is used in the Controller like:   AccessRequestValidator validator = new AccessRequestValidator(); validator.validate(accessRequestBean, result);

Comment: @wuntee You really do not have a Spring managed bean. If you create some instance by using new operator, how can Spring manage your instance ? I will show you how to get your goal

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow what you show above, I am still getting a null pointer:

context.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wuntee.taac"/>
```

AccessRequestValidator.java

```
package com.wuntee.taac.validator;

@Component
public class AccessRequestValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccessCache userAccessCache;
...
}
```

business-context.xml:

```
   <bean id="userAccessCache" class="com.wuntee.taac.controller.UserAccessCache">
        <property name="cadaDao" ref="cadaDao" />
        <property name="adDao" ref="adDao" />
   </bean>
```

Does the scanner recursively scan the tree?

Comment: Strange, I'm seeing the same thing in my project now. A @Component-annotated Validator with an @Autowired field, but it's never wired up and remains null.

Comment: Update: I found my mistake. In my controller, I had an @InitBinder method with this code:

binder.setValidator(new FooValidator());

So while Spring managed *a* FooValidator, I set my controller to use a different, unmanaged one. I just changed it to an autowired FooValidator.