# Manually validate with a custom validator without default constructor

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, javax

I have a custom validation with annotations such as:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniquePropertyValidator.class)
public @interface UniqueProperty {

    String message() default "sample message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

here's my validator:

```
public class UniquePropertyValidator extends JdbcDaoSupport implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueProperty, UniquePropertyClass> {

    @Inject public UniquePropertyValidator(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueProperty property) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UniquePropertyClass propertyClass, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) { return some boolean; }
}
```

and I am trying to use it as following:

```
SpringValidatorAdapter adapter = new SpringValidatorAdapter(validator);
BeanPropertyBindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(propertyClass, propertyClass.getClass().getName());
adapter.validate(propertyClass, result, UniquePropertyClass.SomeValidationGroup.class);

if (result.hasErrors())
    throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(null, result);
```

however I am getting this error:

```
HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: class some.package.UniquePropertyValidator.
```

Now, I am well aware that my validator class does not have a default constructor without any method parameters. However, the following works with the exact annotation and validator:

```
public someMethod(@Validated(value = UniquePropertyClass.SomeValidationGroup.class) @RequestBody UniquePropertyClass propertyClass)
```

What I am asking is; is there a way to manually validate without the default constructor.

P.S. The reason why I cannot use `@Validated` (the working example above) is:

I have a `@PathVariable` (say `id`) and before validating `@RequestBody UniquePropertyClass propertyClass` object, I need to set the `id` of `UniquePropertyClass` object before validating it, since I could not find a way to bind the `@PathVariable` into `@RequestBody` field and validate on the fly with `@Validated`. So giving a hint on how to make this work would also be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create default constructor for the UniquePropertyValidator and add @Component annotation. Then just add

```
@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;
```

to inject the datasource rather than init it from Constructor. (See more for [autowiring objects in validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732993/how-to-autowire-objects-in-validator-classes))

UPDATE you can get the bean from context (see
[Spring get current ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827548/spring-get-current-applicationcontext) )

Comment: Doesn't Spring always create a new instance with `adapter.validate(propertyClass, result, UniquePropertyClass.SomeValidationGroup.class);` instead of using the one that is present in the application context when I use `@Component`? Or will it only create a new one, since it could not find one in the application context?

Comment: It used the one that is in the application context instead of creating a new one. Thanks!